# Convert date format in PHP (without SQL)

Tags: php

How to convert date from `yyyy:mm:dd` to `yyyy-m-dd` and `yyyy:mm:dd` (without leading zero for the month) to `yyyy-m-dd` (with leading zero to month)?

Comment: you can explode the string : with -

Comment: well, i kinda unfamiliar with it.
After split the date, how to concat it?
thanks. ^^

Comment: implode function, but i think there is far more better answer delow and much easier way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$dateFrom ="2012:8:2";
$dateTo =  str_replace(":","-",$dateFrom);
$dateTo = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dateTo));
echo $dateTo;
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and then use [DateTime::format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

***Example:***

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y:m:d', '2012:08:02');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');

// without leading zero for month
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y:n:d', '2012:8:02');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: i tried to change '2012:08:02' with a variable, and it failed.
any idea? ^^

Comment: @user1545296 So what is the value of your variable?

Comment: 2012:07:08
it was user input.

Comment: @user1545296 So it could be anything else, try `var_dump` the variable and see what it is .

Comment: the result of var_dump: string(10) "2012:07:08"

Answer (score 2):

Use the `$date=strtotime($date)` function to get the date in **unix timestamp**. After that you can use the `date("Y-m-d",$date)` function to convert it to the format you want.Here's an example:

```
$date=strtotime($olddate);
$date=date("Y-m-d",$date);
echo $date; // Now this will show you the date in the format you wanted :)
```

Comment: `strtotime` won't recognize the format of `yyyy:mm:dd`, `strtotime('2012:08:02')` will return `false`.

Comment: $olddate=2012:07:08   
after strtotim//echo $date: no output

i dont know, why its happened? ^^, sorry, im a newbie

Comment: @user1545296 As I said, `strtotime` won't recognize the format of `yyyy:mm:dd`, it will return false instead of the unix timestamp.

Comment: The date is string so you have to quote it.
$olddate='2012:07:08';

Comment: @xdazz You are right seems YYYY:mm:dd isn't a valid date format.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

`date` will not understand `:` as a separator, so you will need to replace that with a separator that it understands, like `/` or `-`, with [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

Code:

```
$orig_date = '2012:8:2';
$final_date = date('Y-n-d', str_replace(':', '/', $orig_date));
echo $final_date; // Result: 2012-8-02
```

Answer (score 0):

Use date() function

```
echo date('Y-m-d'); // for 1st case (replacing ':' with '-')
echo date('Y-j-d'); // for 2nd case (without leading zero)
```